# codeigniter Image uploading error

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

```
public function getbasicinfo()
{
    if($this->form_validation->run('basicinfo')==TRUE) {
      $data=$this->input->post();

       $config = [
                'upload_path'   => 'assets/img/jobseeker',
                'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
                'max_size'      => '10000',
                'max_width'     => '1024',
                'max_height'    => '768',
                'overwrite'     =>  TRUE,
               'encrypt_name'  =>  FALSE,
                'remove_spaces' =>  TRUE
        ];

        if ( ! is_dir($config['upload_path']) ) die("THE UPLOAD DIRECTORY DOES NOT EXIST");
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))
        {
            $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $this->session->set_flashdata('image',$error);
                redirect('Jobseeker_profile/editbasicinfo');
        }
        $img = $this->upload->data();
        $data['image']=$img['file_name'].$id;
        $this->load->model('jobseeker_profilemodel','profile');              
        $query=$this->profile->basicinfo($data);
        if ($query==TRUE) {
            redirect('jobseeker/jobpreference');
        }

    }else{
        $this->load->view('jobseeker/editBasicInfoMyProfile');
   }    
}
```

while uploading image using above method gives following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function do_upload() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\application\controllers\Jobseeker_profile.php:53 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(360): Jobseeker_profile->getbasicinfo() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\index.php(202): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\application\controllers\Jobseeker_profile.php on line 53

Comment: where you define `do_upload` function?

Answer (score 1):

You missing  `do_upload` function definition and here is fixed the code

Here is HTML sample code

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Upload Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>

            <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

            <br /><br />

            <input type="submit" value="upload" />

        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is Sample PHP code for Upload image

```
 function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
```

Here is the structure of sample class for `do_upload` function, i think this will help you to understand the `do_upload` function definition

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }
```